# Web service error in mvc is UNKNOWN METHOD NAME How to resolve this?

Tags: c#, web-services

Hello Everyone i have a web service am calling the web service from Jquery ajax the error am getting is

**Unknown web method BindDESG.
Parameter name: methodName**

**My method is like this**

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<ListItem> BindDESG()
    {
        AdoConClass getado = new AdoConClass();
        string query = "select Pk_DeptId,DepartmentName from emp_Master_Department where IsActive=1";
        DataTable dt=getado.retrievedata(query);
        List<ListItem> Desg = new List<ListItem>();

        if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            Desg.Add(new ListItem
            {
                Value = dt.Rows[0]["Pk_DeptId"].ToString(),
                Text = dt.Rows[0]["DepartmentName"].ToString()
            });
        }
        return Desg;
    }
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../../Services/Employee/BindDesgDDL.asmx/BindDESG',
        data: { },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            var ddlCustomers = $("[id*=sDesg]");
            ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
            $.each(r.d, function () {
                ddlCustomers.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
            });
        },
        error: function (msg) { alert(msg); }
    });
});
```

});

Method is public and static but i don't know why the error is coming...
Please help me...

Comment: you better include your Jquery ajax code as well in the question. is this c# code also in the same page code behind file?

Comment: Does this method appear in the WSDL for the web service?

Comment: I have add my jquery code in question plz find that.... @Damith

Comment: @Raviteja remove the `static` from the web method

Comment: Thanx Damith it is working ........ @Damith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method which am using is static method ....

I just removed the static from the method the non-static method is executed ....